# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS hardware updates

Tags: 14.04, updates, dell, xps

According to information on [Release end of life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) Ubuntu site, more precisely the following picture.

[image]

It seems there should be hardware related updates still available on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
And this is something which does not reflects the latest high-end Ubuntu powered laptops shipped by Dell.
I'm owner of one of such devices, XPS 13 9343, shipped with Ubuntu 14.04. In overall it makes really good impression.
The problem is that Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't support all of its devices (correctly).
There are nice articles over the web which describes how to install 3.19 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04 to make Ubuntu supports the laptop devices better. Linking just one of them: [a blog post](http://mclements.net/Mike/mrc-blog/blog-150605.html).
I can confirm 3.19 kernel does help Ubuntu to better handle the laptop, still doesn't solve all the issues.

Nevertheless I'm interested **technically whose responsibility is to provide hardware related updates?** Obviously Dell shouldn't ship laptops which are not ready. On the other hand there is an attached picture which is telling that Ubuntu will provide hardware updates till early 2016.
**Is it recommended to stick with default 3.13 kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 and just wait for updates from Ubuntu which will solve all the hardware related issues?** The laptops were shipped in February(?) AFAIK so it is already 6 months of waiting for the early buyers.

Comment: This: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack should help you. If you want better support for newer hardware you should use the LTS enablement stack  (at the moment this means kernel 3.16)

Comment: I think (this means I don't know for sure and am too lazy to research! - if it's wrong, please may anybody correct me) that Dell and most other laptop manufacturers don't care too much about supporting Linux/Ubuntu systems and providing drivers for their hardware for them, as those OS are a tiny minority in contrast to the Windows users. Most development comes from the community in form of less-powerful but more versatile generic open-source drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is available as 14.04.2. It has 3.16 kernel by default.

In August 2015 version 14.04.3 will be released with kernel 3.19.

This kernel 3.19 is already available to install from Ubuntu repositories by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

You did not mention which specific hardware problems you have. If you ask specific questions, it may appear that these issues can be solved without changing kernels.

You can also install latest mainline kernels like 4.1 from [Mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

It is definitely Dell's responsibility to fix hardware issues since they ship laptops with Ubuntu OEM.

Comment: Some of the issues are listed on linked blog post, there is a big list on Dell forum. There is no point to cover them here. Thank you for the answer, it is totally on point. Also this is a good news about the 14.04.3 coming release which will solves most of the issues.

Comment: @j But you do need to wait for 14.04.3 or re-install it. You can upgrade kernel now.